# Correct spacing between expressions after converting from infix to postfix expression

Tags: java, postfix-notation, infix-notation

Currently I have a program that converts infix expressions to postfix. However, I want my postfix output to be like so:

Infix expression: `(11+11)*(11+11)`

Current postfix expression: `11 11+ 11 11+*`

Desired postfix expression: `11 11 + 11 11 + *`

I am not exactly able to figure out what changes I should make to my code so I can achieve my desired result.

My code:

```
private int Prec(Character ch)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;

        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '%':
            return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override public T visitEval(ExpAnalyserParser.EvalContext ctx) {

    String postfix = new String("");
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i< ctx.getText().length(); i++) {
        char c = ctx.getText().charAt(i);

        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            postfix += c;
        }

        else if (c == '(')
            stack.push(c);

        else if (c == ')') {
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(')
                postfix += (stack.pop());

            if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '(')
                System.out.println("Invalid Expression");
            else
                stack.pop();
        }
        else {
            postfix += " ";
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && Prec(c) <= Prec(stack.peek()))
                postfix += (stack.pop());
            stack.push(c);
        }

    }

    while (!stack.isEmpty()){
        postfix += (stack.pop());

    }

    try(FileWriter out = new FileWriter("postfix.txt")){
        out.write(postfix.toString());
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Infix Expression: " + ctx.getText());
    return (T) postfix;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (!stack.isEmpty() && Prec(c) <= Prec(stack.peek()))
                postfix += " " + (stack.pop());
```

Add an extra space before you add the operator everywhere you add an operator